# Responsive design vertical align issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created a page with two divs. The idea of the page is that div on the left should not have scroll bar, so it's position is set to fixed. Only div on the right should have scroll bar. It does work on desktop size, but in responsive design I want both divs have a width of 100%. So they should be aligned one after another. And the problem is that I don't know what property should I use to achieve this vertical align (with my code second div is climbing on top of first). Any ideas?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100vh;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-image: url('http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/roomandboard/ramsey_939528_15e1_g?$str_g$&size=960,607&scl=1');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position: fixed;
}

.secondDiv {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

p {
  line-height: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .firstDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height:30%;
    float: left;
  }

  .secondDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Idea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="firstDiv">

  </div>

  <div class="secondDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a nibh in neque condimentum porta. Nunc consequat fermentum iaculis. Maecenas convallis efficitur nulla, eleifend commodo justo pellentesque quis. Fusce eu arcu nec orci lacinia convallis a vel ex. In vehicula efficitur magna eget lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque lacinia ante vitae nisl dignissim tempus. Nullam vitae sapien et lorem efficitur ullamcorper quis non massa. Vestibulum eu ornare sapien. Morbi molestie urna eros, sed egestas ipsum tincidunt in. Vivamus nec ullamcorper ante. Donec ut dui a mauris volutpat suscipit vitae pharetra diam. Maecenas euismod augue arcu, quis consectetur ligula elementum ac.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove position:fixed to firstDiv and make it float:left and in media query make firstDiv height to 30vh instead of 30%

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100vh;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-image: url('http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/roomandboard/ramsey_939528_15e1_g?$str_g$&size=960,607&scl=1');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  float: left;
}

.secondDiv {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

p {
  line-height: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .firstDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height:30vh;
  }

  .secondDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Idea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="firstDiv">

  </div>

  <div class="secondDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a nibh in neque condimentum porta. Nunc consequat fermentum iaculis. Maecenas convallis efficitur nulla, eleifend commodo justo pellentesque quis. Fusce eu arcu nec orci lacinia convallis a vel ex. In vehicula efficitur magna eget lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque lacinia ante vitae nisl dignissim tempus. Nullam vitae sapien et lorem efficitur ullamcorper quis non massa. Vestibulum eu ornare sapien. Morbi molestie urna eros, sed egestas ipsum tincidunt in. Vivamus nec ullamcorper ante. Donec ut dui a mauris volutpat suscipit vitae pharetra diam. Maecenas euismod augue arcu, quis consectetur ligula elementum ac.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin-top` to second div from height of first div ..

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100vh;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-image: url('http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/roomandboard/ramsey_939528_15e1_g?$str_g$&size=960,607&scl=1');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position: fixed;
}

.secondDiv {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

p {
  line-height: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .firstDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height:30%;
    float: left;
  }

  .secondDiv {
    margin-top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Idea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="firstDiv">

  </div>

  <div class="secondDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a nibh in neque condimentum porta. Nunc consequat fermentum iaculis. Maecenas convallis efficitur nulla, eleifend commodo justo pellentesque quis. Fusce eu arcu nec orci lacinia convallis a vel ex. In vehicula efficitur magna eget lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque lacinia ante vitae nisl dignissim tempus. Nullam vitae sapien et lorem efficitur ullamcorper quis non massa. Vestibulum eu ornare sapien. Morbi molestie urna eros, sed egestas ipsum tincidunt in. Vivamus nec ullamcorper ante. Donec ut dui a mauris volutpat suscipit vitae pharetra diam. Maecenas euismod augue arcu, quis consectetur ligula elementum ac.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add `margin-top:30%;` to your `.secondDiv` style (the one inside the media tag). Also, the `float` style is unnecessary.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100vh;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-image: url('http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/roomandboard/ramsey_939528_15e1_g?$str_g$&size=960,607&scl=1');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position: fixed;
}

.secondDiv {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

p {
  line-height: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .firstDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height:30%;
  }

  .secondDiv {
    margin-top:30%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Idea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="firstDiv">

  </div>

  <div class="secondDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a nibh in neque condimentum porta. Nunc consequat fermentum iaculis. Maecenas convallis efficitur nulla, eleifend commodo justo pellentesque quis. Fusce eu arcu nec orci lacinia convallis a vel ex. In vehicula efficitur magna eget lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque lacinia ante vitae nisl dignissim tempus. Nullam vitae sapien et lorem efficitur ullamcorper quis non massa. Vestibulum eu ornare sapien. Morbi molestie urna eros, sed egestas ipsum tincidunt in. Vivamus nec ullamcorper ante. Donec ut dui a mauris volutpat suscipit vitae pharetra diam. Maecenas euismod augue arcu, quis consectetur ligula elementum ac.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```